# Python Selenium: selecionar um elemento dentro de um submenu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Alguma ideia de como selecionar o menu "pesquisar contratos"? [image: Menu e código fonte]

estou usando o webdriver (seleniun). Já testei find_element_by:
**td**: não consegui identificar qual seria o índice correto (fiz com o menu anterior, "gestão de contrato..." e deu certo, com "pesquisar contrato" não);
**xpath**: o xpath deste item muda a cada carregamento da página;
**classe menuItem**: trouxe os itens do menu anterior;
**text_link:** não localizado;
**css td.menuItemSeleccionado:** não localizado;
**classe menuItemSeleccionado**: não localizado

Minhas ideias acabaram, sou nova no python. Alguém me ajuda por favor?

Comment: Já tentou `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text() = 'Pesquisa Contrato']")` ou `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text() = 'Pesquisa Contrato']")`

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text() = 'Pesquisa Contrato']"}

Answer (score -3):

Olá, é possível que a busca pelo elemento possa estar com dificuldades relacionada a 'td'. Aconselho o uso da busca por CSS_SELECTOR.

'''

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

contatos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class="menuItemSelecionado"]')
```

'''

Comment: deu esse erro:      navegador.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="menuItemSeleccionado"]')[1].click()
IndexError: list index out of range          Com índice 0 não fez nada